# How to delete letters using R

Tags: regex, r

I would like to remove letters and symbols from a line using R,

```
temp <- " 20.9Â°C \n              a 07"
```

everything from Â to the end, and get only

```
20.9
```

I have used this expression, but something fails...

```
temp2 <- ( gsub("Â°C \n*?","", temp,  ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: `gsub("^\ +|Â°.*$", "", temp)` will get you back `20.9` but you might beed a better regex depending on what you needs really are.

Comment: `07` are also digits, so what is your rule of thumb for what to remove and what to keep?

Comment: `as.numeric(scan(text=gsub("[^.0-9]", " ", temp), what="", sep=""))#[1] 20.9  7.0`  If you need both numbers

Comment: Thank you very much, I only need the first digits! It works properly!

Comment: Note that if these are temperatures in C then that second solution won't find negative temperatures - in fact it will return negative numbers as positive!

Comment: In order to avoid opening another question, how can I transform 25/08/14 in 25-08-2014? thank you very much

Comment: This would get you the first number , `sub('^\\D*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*', '\\1', temp)`

Comment: BTW it looks like you have a windows-1252 string, not utf-8 - `iconv(" 20.9Â°C", "UTF-8", "windows-1252")` will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you state you only want `20.9` from your string and everything after removed, this will do the trick.

```
> temp <- ' 20.9Â°C \n              a 07'
> temp2 <- sub('^ (.*?)Â[^Â]+', '\\1', temp)
> temp2
## [1] "20.9"
```

If you end up needing to extract temperatures, you could start off with something like this:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> temp <- ' -0.5°C \n \n   20.9Â°C      a +25.0°C'
> temp2 <- strapply(temp, '([+-]?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)')[[1]]
## [1] "-0.5"  "20.9"  "+25.0"
```

Based off your comment, how can I transform `25/08/14` to `25-08-2014` ?

```
gsub('([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})', '\\1-\\2-20\\3', '25/08/14')
## [1] "25-08-2014"
```

Comment: I will consider this function strapply